# Count string occurence in array using only reduce does not read last value

Tags: javascript, reduce

I would make a program usin reduce that counts number of occurence of a string in an array.

I should only use reduces.

Here's my program.

```
function countWords(inputWords) {
  let obj={};
  inputWords.reduce((curr,next )=> {
     obj[curr]=0;
    inputWords.reduce((current,next2)=> {
      if(curr===current) {
        obj[curr]++;
      }
      return next2
    });
    return next;
  })
  return obj
}
```

What my result prints

> My result :   { exercitation: 1, non: 1, irure: 1, commodo: 3, velit:
>   2, officia: 1, consectetur: 4, laboris: 2, est: 2, aliquip: 1,
>   excepteur: 1, consequat: 1, magna: 1, id: 1, eiusmod: 1, veniam: 1,
>   anim: 1, ullamco: 1, elit: 2, nulla: 1, cupidatat: 2, proident: 1,
>   lorem: 1, ad: 1, quis: 1, dolore: 1, occaecat: 1, aliqua: 1, tempor:
>   1, do: 1, dolor: 1, labore: 1 }

What is expected:

> Expected result : { exercitation: 1, non: 1, irure: 1, commodo: 3,
>   velit: 2, officia: 1, consectetur: 4, laboris: 2, est: 2, aliquip: 1,
>   excepteur: 1, consequat: 1, magna: 1, id: 1, eiusmod: 1, veniam: 1,
>   anim: 1, ullamco: 1, elit: 2, nulla: 1, cupidatat: 2, proident: 1,
>   lorem: 1, ad: 1, quis: 1, dolore: 1, occaecat: 1, aliqua: 1, tempor:
>   1, do: 1, dolor: 1, labore: 1, **amet: 1 }**

Here's the inputs words:

> Input:[ 'exercitation', 'non', 'irure', 'commodo', 'velit', 'officia',
>   'consectetur', 'commodo', 'laboris', 'est', 'aliquip', 'excepteur',
>   'consequat', 'consectetur', 'magna', 'id', 'eiusmod', 'veniam',
>   'anim', 'consectetur', 'ullamco', 'elit', 'nulla', 'cupidatat',
>   'proident', 'commodo', 'laboris', 'est', 'lorem', 'consectetur',
>   'elit', 'ad', 'quis', 'dolore', 'occaecat', 'aliqua', 'cupidatat',
>   'tempor', 'do', 'dolor', 'velit', 'labore', 'amet' ]

Comment: You’re not utilizing `reduce` correctly. See this [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Counting_instances_of_values_in_an_object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not be an requirement of using a reduce inside another reduce method.
In the object check if the key exist or not, if not then create the key in the object otherwise update it's value by 1

```js
let input = ['exercitation', 'non', 'irure', 'commodo', 'velit', 'officia', 'consectetur', 'commodo', 'laboris', 'est', 'aliquip', 'excepteur', 'consequat', 'consectetur', 'magna', 'id', 'eiusmod', 'veniam', 'anim', 'consectetur', 'ullamco', 'elit', 'nulla', 'cupidatat', 'proident', 'commodo', 'laboris', 'est', 'lorem', 'consectetur', 'elit', 'ad', 'quis', 'dolore', 'occaecat', 'aliqua', 'cupidatat', 'tempor', 'do', 'dolor', 'velit', 'labore', 'amet']

let result = input.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(curr)) {
    acc[curr] = 1;
  } else {
    acc[curr] += 1;
  }
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks , can you expain to me why my solution does not work ?

Answer (score 1):

You should always return the object containing frequencies within the reducer. The initial object can be the second parameter of `Array.reduce`.

So, here's a oneliner for you:

```js
(() => {
  const input = ['exercitation', 'non', 'irure', 'commodo', 'velit', 'officia', 
    'consectetur', 'commodo', 'laboris', 'est', 'aliquip', 'excepteur', 'consequat', 
    'consectetur', 'magna', 'id', 'eiusmod', 'veniam', 'anim', 'consectetur', 
    'ullamco', 'elit', 'nulla', 'cupidatat', 'proident', 'commodo', 'laboris', 'est', 
    'lorem', 'consectetur', 'elit', 'ad', 'quis', 'dolore', 'occaecat', 'aliqua', 
    'cupidatat', 'tempor', 'do', 'dolor', 'velit', 'labore', 'amet'];
  console.log(input.reduce( (f, v) => v in f ? (f[v] += 1, f) : (f[v] = 1, f), {}));
  /* which can also be written as:
    input.reduce( (frequencies, value) => {
      if (frequencies[value]) {
        // frequencies contains the value key, so increment
        frequencies[value] += 1;
      } else {
        // add value to frequencies and initialize ([value] = 1)
        frequencies[value] = 1;
      }
      // return the now updated frequencies object for further use
      return frequencies;
    }, {});
    // ^ the initial frequencies object
  */
})();
```